# SCSS child class over riding parent class

Tags: css, sass

I have this:

```
tr {
          &.selected {
            background-color: #424253;
          }
          td {
            &.current-month {
              background-color: #2c3645;
            }
            &.last {
              background-color: #1e252f;
              font-weight: bold;
            }
          }
        }
```

The rule in tr:

```
&.selected {
        background-color: #424253;
      }
```

As expected, is being overridden by the td rules:

```
&.current-month {
          background-color: #2c3645;
        }
&.last {
          background-color: #1e252f;
          font-weight: bold;
        }
```

How do I make it so the tr class `selected` always overrules any td class affecting `background-color` (without using !important)?

Answer (score 0):

You can give same specificity as the *current-month* and *last* classes and writing **selected** at the end will take more precision and overrides others.

```
tr {              
          td {
            &.current-month {
              background-color: #2c3645;
            }
            &.last {
              background-color: #1e252f;
              font-weight: bold;
            }
            &.selected {
            background-color: #424253;
          }
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could override the background for all td elements that have a class assigned:

```
tr {
  &.selected {
    background-color: #424253;
    &[class] {
      background-color: #424253;
    }
  }
  td {
    &.current-month {
      background-color: #2c3645;
    }
    &.last {
      background-color: #1e252f;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
  }
}
```

but i also think in this case it would be totally ok to use !important.
Another solution, if you would use classes for tr and td elements would be this:

```
.table-row {
  .table-cell {
    &.current-month {
      background-color: #2c3645;
    }
    &.last {
      background-color: #1e252f;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    @at-root .selected#{&} {
      background-color: #424253;
    }
  }
}
```